# System V Semaphore works inconsistently

Tags: c, semaphore

Okay folks, I give up. I hope you're able to help me somehow.

I'm currently trying to write a code which executes several "generic" processes and one backup process. The idea being that there can be multiple running processes but if the backup process wants to start, then no new processes are created and the backup process is waiting for the other ones to end.

The generic processes are handled in the following function:

```c
int manageProcess(int* data, int* numProcesses, int semId, int time)
{
    if(semop(semId, &semwait2, 1) < 0) //semaphore 2 wait
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "Error at semop wait 2.\n");
        return 7;
    }
    if(++(*numProcesses) == 1)
    {
        if(semop(semId, &semwait1, 1) < 0) //semaphore 1 wait
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "Error at semop wait 1.\n");
            return 7;
        }
    }   
    if(semop(semId, &semsignal2, 1) < 0) //semaphore 2 signal
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "Error at semop signal 2.\n");
        return 7;
    }
    
    fprintf(stdout, "Process %d: Data read: %d, Execution time: %d minutes\n", getpid(), *data, time);
    sleep(time * 60);
    fprintf(stdout, "Process %d: Terminated\n", getpid());

    if(semop(semId, &semwait2, 1) < 0) //semaphore 2 wait
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "Error at semop wait 2.\n");
        return 7;
    }
    if(--(*numProcesses) == 0)
    {
        if(semop(semId, &semsignal1, 1) < 0) //semaphore 1 signal
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "Error at semop signal 1.\n");
            return 7;
        }
        printf("semop signal.\n"); //should be called if backup process is able to start
    }   
    if(semop(semId, &semsignal2, 1) < 0) //semaphore 2 signal
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "Error at semop signal 2.\n");
        return 7;
    }
    
    return 0;
}//manageProcess
```

This seems a lot, so let me break it out for you. There is the pointer `numProcesses` which points to a shared memory which tracks the number of generic processes currently running. Every time a process enters this function, the value of `numProcesses` is incremented, decremented if the process reaches the end of the function. Since multiple processes can enter this function all at once, I added Semaphore 2 to make sure that only one process is able to alter the shared memory.

Semaphore 1 is more interesting. If `*numProcesses` at the beginning of the function is 1, then the wait operation of semaphore 1 is called. This blocks the backup process from starting since at least one generic process is running. If `*numProcesses` at the end of the function is 0, meaning no generic process is currently running, then the signal operation of semaphore 1 is called, giving the backup process permission to start.

Here is the code for the backup process:

```c
while(1)
        {
            if(semop(semId, &semwait0, 1) < 0) //semaphore 0 wait
            {
                fprintf(stdout, "Error at semop wait 0.\n");
                return 7;
            }
            fprintf(stdout, "Initiating backup process. Waiting for other processes to end.\n");
            if(semop(semId, &semwait1, 1) < 0) //semaphore 1 wait
            {
                fprintf(stdout, "Error at semop wait 1.\n");
                return 7;
            }
            fprintf(stdout, "Backup process started.\n");
            *data = rand();
            sleep(15);
            fprintf(stdout, "Exiting backup process.\n");
            if(semop(semId, &semsignal1, 1) < 0) //semaphore 1 signal
            {
                fprintf(stdout, "Error at semop signal 1.\n");
                return 7;
            }
            if(semop(semId, &semsignal0, 1) < 0) //semaphore 0 signal
            {
                fprintf(stdout, "Error at semop signal 0.\n");
                return 7;
            }
            sleep(3 * 60);
        }
```

Semaphore 1 is supposed to block the backup process of entering the critical area if generic processes are still running. However it does it inconsistently, sometimes it works, other times it doesn't. The output looks like this:

```
Two incoming processes.
Process 5927: Data read: 1278759833, Execution time: 4 minutes
Process 5928: Data read: 1278759833, Execution time: 1 minutes
Process 5928: Terminated
Running processes: 1.
Two incoming processes.
Process 6146: Data read: 1278759833, Execution time: 3 minutes
Process 6147: Data read: 1278759833, Execution time: 4 minutes
Running processes: 3.
Two incoming processes.
Process 6352: Data read: 1278759833, Execution time: 2 minutes
Process 6353: Data read: 1278759833, Execution time: 1 minutes
Initiating backup process. Waiting for other processes to end.
Process 6353: Terminated
Process 5927: Terminated
Backup process started.
Process 6146: Terminated
Process 6352: Terminated
Exiting backup process.
```

As you can see, after it initiated the backup process, it did wait for the other processes to end, meaning semaphore 1 blocked the backup process, however it still launched while other processes were still running. I really have no idea what my mistake is. Admittedly, I'm not really well-versed in C, so excuse my perhaps beginner mistakes. :)

PS: If you're interested, Semaphore 0 simply blocks the creation of new processes if the backup process wants to run. However, it works so I didn't explain it any further.

EDIT: Okay, I analyzed all the runs of my code and apperently the wait and signal operation have to be called in the same process for it to work. If a process calls the wait operation and then exits, then implicitly the signal operation is called therefore starting the backup process. This is just a theory but after analyzing all the outputs I think this is my answer.